# StringFormat ("0214" to "02:14")

Tags: wpf, vb.net, string-formatting

I have a String "0214" i would like te present this as 02:14 is this possible in wpf with stringFormat and binding.

If it would be an integer i could do it like bellow but the problem is that the "0" disapears and becomes Int "214" But this is not good for placing in the database because it requires 4 numbers.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Start" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Start, StringFormat={}{0:00\:00}}"/>
```

output: '02:14'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringFormat` is not actually used to format strings. It's used to format non-string values into strings.

You can use an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) however to convert your string into the format you want. Another option would be to alter your data class to expose a read-only `FormattedStart` property which returns the formatted value.

Answer (score 0):

- Use a converter to split the input string and return the two parts separated by a `:`
- Convert to an int and use `StringFormat={}{0:00\\:00}}` (This should be the equivalent of `int.ToString("00':'00")`